# Bi-directional current source based on MOSFET or IGBT

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, switches, current-source, igbt

I am studying a bi-directional current source based on precision difference amplifiers and the MOSFETs, which is described on the website https://www.edn.com/simple-precise-bi-directional-current-source/ [image]

1. This circuit seems to be rigid for the parameters of the operational amplifier. I am wondering how to choose the appropriate amplifiers and MOSFETs.
2. In this circuit, the batteries are used. Because my target is to switch off a 10mH inductive load with 3.5A in an extremely short time (<50us) and turn it on within 1~2ms, the inductive load will generate a large emf inverse voltage due to large dI/dt. Is there a way to convert these two batteries into the standard voltage sources? In that case, the circuit is compatible with the real constant voltage source. At the same time, I hope that the load is connected to the MOSFETs rather than the voltage source, therefore, I can use MOSFETs with large higher Vds to bear large inverse voltage.
3. Given the requirement of voltage, it seems IGBT is also a good choice that can handle the large voltage and large current. NMOSFET is easy to be replaced, however, I have no clue about the PMOSPET. Is there a circuit element that can invert the voltage sign driving the IGBT as the PMOSFET?
4. To compensate for the eddy-current induced magnetic field in the inductive load, I hope to perform an input signal with some spikes rather than a TTL signal. What kind of circuit can generate such a tunable waveform?

[image]

Comment: What kind of waveform would you expect in the inductor?

Comment: _"To compensate for the eddy-current induced magnetic field in the inductive load,"_ - What effect do you expect this 'eddy-current induced magnetic field' to have? _"my target is to switch off a 10mH inductive load with 3.5A in an extremely short time (<50us) and turn it on within 1~2ms,"_ - Why do you want to do this, and why must the load have an inductance of 10mH?

Comment: Does the desired waveform require a linear current source? It would be much simpler to use switching...

Comment: If you explicitly tell us what is your load and why you need to switch it that fast, we could be able to give you alternative solutions. As it stands, as several others have said, you are trying to go against the physical behavior of the inductor. In other words, try to explain the actual problem you are trying to solve, with all the necessary context.

Answer (score 3):

> *my target is to switch on/off a 10mH inductive load with 3.5A in an
> extremely short time (<50us), the inductive load will generate a large
> emf inverse voltage due to large dI/dt.*

When "switching **off**" at 3.5 amps per 50 μs, the back-emf will be 700 volts and, to prevent your requirement being ruined by real-world things such as clipping against power rails, you'll need a voltage supply that is +/- 700 volts and, an op-amp capable of delivering that sort of voltage to the MOSFET gates.

Same story when "switching **on**" 3.5 amps in 50 μs; you need to drive the coil with 700 volts.

That isn't really feasible so you probably have to rethink your aim. Calculation: -

$$V = L\cdot\dfrac{di}{dt} = 0.01\times\dfrac{3.5}{50\times 10^{-6}} = 700\text{ volts}$$

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I see that the back-emf will be 700 volts and I plan to clamp this voltage with Zener diodes. This circuit topology seems suitable for my target. However, there are still some challenges: the load is connected to the battery rather than the MOSFET(like a MOSFET switch), and the battery is bearing the back-emf, not MOSFET. I am wondering if it is possible to replace the battery in the voltage source format. In this case, I expect the power MOSFET (or IGBT) bears the back-emf.

Comment: @Rayonde You didn't understand correctly. You don't need to clamp anything. Andy's calculation shows that you cannot produce such a sharp current pulse into your inductive load in the first place, *unless you provide* 700 V to your amplifier. You can switch it off fast (with clamping), but you cannot switch it on fast.

Comment: @tobalt. The requirement of turn-on time can be loosened to several milliseconds (e.g 1ms). I think this is feasible with some series resistors and reasonable voltage spike

Comment: @Rayonde if you clamp to (say) 70 volts, then the 3.5 amps will take ten times longer to reduce to zero amps. This does not appear to be what you want. Same when driving the coil; 70 volts  will drive a di/dt of 3.5 amps per 500 μs and not 50 μs. This is how inductors work.

Comment: @Rayonde What source voltage do you have available?

Answer (score 0):

EE&O ...

For your information, here is what happens with such "load".
NB: rise time (50us for the first 2 pulses and 100us for the other 2) is included in the generator. Note the different Back-emf that can't be suppressed.

[image]

Here is another solution. NB: Back-emf ~ 5kV.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I suppose that the extremely high voltage spike can be avoided by clamping the inductive load using Zender diodes. The back-emf can be locked below 1kV which is acceptable for some power MOSFET or IGBT. Now the challenge is that the above circuit uses the battery as a power source, I am figuring out a way to convert it to the standard layout similar to the MOSFET switch and further replace MOSFET by IGBT.

Answer (score 0):

As demonstrated by Andy, you need a very large supply voltage in order to switch on the current fast enough for your design goal.

With some magnetic engineering you can get away with a lower supply voltage. The idea is to wind a second coil over your inductor core to create a transformer. While keeping your load circuit open, slowly charge your aux winding with current. Then close the LOAD switch; then open the CHARGE switch. The switches still need to be rated for the full flyback voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG390x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are working against the physical reality of the inductor.

I'll provide you this approach based on energy concepts.

An inductor in which the current is \$i\$ will hold an amount of energy in its magnetic field given by:

\$
E_L(t) = \frac 1 2 L i^2(t)
\$

Note the time dependency: this is true at any given instant of time.

Now, with \$ L = 10mH\$ and \$ i = 3.5A\$ you get \$ E_L \approx 61 mJ \$ of energy.

Therefore, to switch that load in a time equal to \$ \Delta t = 50 \mu s \$
you need an average power given by:

\$
P = \frac{\Delta E_L} {\Delta t} = \frac{61 mJ}{50 \mu s}\approx 1225 W
\$

Moreover, if you reduce the switching time by a factor of (say) ten, then your power requirement rises by ten: \$~12kW\$.

Hence you should really think your problem over: any system capable of switching your load in such a short time should be rated for that level of power, i.e. more than \$ ~1.2 kW \$!

And that's only the power that must be delivered to the load, not counting losses in the driver system and a sound safety margin.

In summary, just to be conservative and without a specific circuit to reason about, I'll go for about double that figure for the power rating of your driver system (and the relative power supplies).

Bottom line: **do you really need a driver system rated for *at least* \$~3kW\$ ?!?**

Comment: Confirmed the power needed. All that energy is quasi "used" in a resistor ( my R6 in the second circuit is shown).